# In what cases can we say "her size/color of shoes"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **1a.** *The size of **her** shoes is six*.
>
> **1b.** ***Her*** size of shoes is six.

---

> **2a.** *The size of **her** shoes depends on whether her legs are swollen up or not*.​
>
> **2b.** ***Her*** size of shoes depends on whether her legs are swollen up or not.​

---

> **3a.** *The color of **her** shoes is brown*.
>
> **3b.** ***Her*** color of shoes is brown.

---

> **4a.** *The favorite color of **her** shoes is red*.
>
> **4b.** ***Her*** favorite color of shoes is red.

---

What variants are correct?

For me all **b**-variants have the same meanings as **a**. Why am I wrong?

In what cases can we say "***her*** size/color of shoes"?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Lets start with the easy one. I will add some commas. Then we need to change **of** for **in**, because we are talking about what she **wears** not what she **possesses**. However in items 1 to 6 we have statements about possession of and wearing the shoes.

> 4a. The favourite colour of her shoes, is red. **The favourite colour in her shoes** But this does not work
>
> 4b. Her favourite colour of shoes is red. **Her favourite colour in shoes** this is OK.

**in** preposition (**WEARING**).[C.E.D](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not)......... not.......... **of** preposition (**POSSESSION**)[C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)

Examples

Do you recognise that man in the grey suit?

A pair of her red shoes

Now lets look at your other items and I will edit as necessary

> 1a. The size of her shoes is six.
>
> 1b. Her size of shoes is six. **wrong**

**Her size in shoes is six.**

> 2a. The size of her shoes depends on whether her legs are swollen up or not.​ **wrong**

The size of **the** shoes **she needs** depends on whether her legs are swollen up or not.​

> 2b. Her size of shoes depends on whether her legs are swollen up or not.​  **wrong**

Her size **in** shoes depends on whether her legs are swollen up or not.​

> 3a. The color of her shoes is brown.
>
> 3b. Her color of shoes is brown **wrong**

**Her colour in shoes is brown**

> 4a. The favourite colour of her shoes, is red. **wrong**

We would use 4b we have no interest in what her shoes like or dislike, only what she likes.

> 4b. Her favourite colour of shoes is red. **wrong**

Her favourite colour in shoes is red